# getjson array jquery undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Good day,
I'm trying to run a simple getJSON to get information from data json, almost done but when running, get undefined in html

Here's my jquery :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $.getJSON("/airport.json?code=bgw", function(data) {
    $('#stage').html('<p> Name: ' + data.result.request.code + '</p>');
    $.each(data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data, function() {
      $("ul").append("<li>Name: "+this['flight.status.text']+"</li><br />");
    });
  });
});
```

data json :

```
`  {
  "result": {
    "response": {
      "airport": {
        "pluginData": {
          "schedule": {
            "arrivals": {
              "data": [
                {
                  "flight": {
                    "status": {
                      "live": true,
                      "text": "Estimated 13:44",
                      "icon": "green",
                      "estimated": null,
                      "ambiguous": false
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: As given in your `data json`, There's no [request] key in your [data.result] object property. Is this your complete version of your `json`?

Comment: Your data.json file is enclosed in back-ticks

Comment: yes is complete  version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing the nested object as `this['flight.status.text']`. I believe you want to do `this.flight.status.text`. See the difference below

```js
var data = [{
  test: {
    deep: {
      nested: {
        object: 1
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  test: {
    deep: {
      nested: {
        object: 2
      }
    }
  }
}];

console.log("Not working");
$.each(data, function() {
  console.log(this['test.deep.nested.object']);
});

console.log("--------------");

console.log("Working");
$.each(data, function() {
  console.log(this.test.deep.nested.object);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, as per your your JSON, `data.result.request.code` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.flight.status.text` to display the text like below

```js
 $(document).ready( function() {
 data={
  "result": {
    "response": {
      "airport": {
        "pluginData": {
          "schedule": {
            "arrivals": {
              "data": [
                {
                  "flight": {
                    "status": {
                      "live": true,
                      "text": "Estimated 13:44",
                      "icon": "green",
                      "estimated": null,
                      "ambiguous": false
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
                      $('#stage').html('<p> Name: ' + 'bgw' + '</p>');  $.each(data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data, function(){
                      $("ul").append("<li>Name: "+this.flight.status.text+"</li><br />");
                       });


 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="stage"></div>
<ul></ul>
```